Meaning of Verb Prefixes such as "be-" and "ver-"
The difference between "behindert" (disabled) and "verhindert" (impeded, prevented) is clear to me, but I got to wondering if anyone here has a list of prefixes such as "be-" and "ver-" with a rough explanation of how they alter the meaning of the verb they prefix.

Wiktionary has it. You can search for German prefixes with "ver-", "be-", "ent-", for example, and will get much more information than can be put into an answer here.

There is no strict rule, but in most cases, "be" adds/constructs something, and has often (not always!) a positive connotation ("befreunden", "bestellen", "bewegen", "bedaten"), while "ver" removes/destroys something and is often negative ("verstellen", "vergessen", "verzichten",...); but this does not work always. For instance, "besorgen" and "versorgen" are both constructive and positive.

@user1934428  the "destructive" prefix is rather "zer-". "ver-" can indeed be both negative or positive, I think that the meaning is usually a kind of processing of the (implied) object. The prefixes "be-"(apply), "er-" (create), "ge-" (use) and "zer-"(destroy) are mostly specialized, while "ver-" has many facets which can overlap with many of those.

The problem with this question is that many of these prefixes are quite old (old enough to be shared with English, for instance verloren and forlorn, verboten and forbidden, the "be-" in "bewitch", "begin" or "beguile", etc.) and the original meaning is not easily discernable from looking at the words built with them.
For instance, here is the etymology of "ver-", according to Kluge/Seebold, "Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen":
The New High German "ver-" comes from Middle High German "ver-", which comes from Old High German "fir-" and "far-". The last two resemble the Old English "for-" and in Old French "fur-".
In an earlier stage (Gothic and also non-germanic languages) there are three different prefixes "faur-", "fair-" and "fra-", which collapsed into one in German and related languages. These prefixes are related to Old Indian "purá", "prá" and "pári", also Greek "peri-", "pro-" and "para-" and Latin "pro-" ("por-") und "per-". (This last information can also be found in the "mother of all etymological dictionaries", the Grimm.)
All these prefixes are related presumably and come from the reconstructed Proto-Indoeuropean root "*per-", which meant "to cross, to go". It is not easy to detect the different meanings in todays forms:

for fair- there are no clear examples
ver- coming from faur- is more space-related ("above something", "to a different location"), for instance verschlafen, versetzen
ver- coming from fra- are words like verarbeiten, verschwinden, verbrauchen, but also in the exact opposite meaning: verlernen, verspielen.

Seebold mentions some literatur with further information, some of it naturally in German:

T. J. Johannisson, Verbal och postverbal partikelkomposition, Dissertation, Lund, 1939

E. Öhmann, Festgabe für U. Pretzel, Berlin, 1963, S327-337

I. Kühnold, H. Wellmann, Wortbildung Bd. 1, Das Verb, Düsseldorf, 1973

A. L. Lloyd, R. Lühr, Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen, Bd. 3, Göttingen und Zürich, 2007

M Philippa u.a., Etymologisch woordenboek van het Nederlands, Bd. 4, Amsterdam, 2009


There is also Max Leopold, "Die Vorsilbe ver- und ihre Geschichte".
...and this was only the one prefix "ver-". Similarily complex for "be-" (again, based on Kluge/Seebold):
"be-" comes from reconstructed germanic "*bi-" (also gothic "bi-", Old English "be-", Old French "bi-") and from what later became the particle "bei".
It can be found (in reduced form) in erbarmen (to take pity), bleiben (to stay), binnen (within, interior) and bange (frightened, worried).
Originally the meaning was strictly local (Old High German bifallan "hinfallen"), was then generalized to a strengthening meaning (e.g. "bedecken") and also for making transitive words out of non-transitive ones (e.g. "beleuchten"). There is also the meaning of "to equip with", like in "bekleiden" (to clothe).
Further reading:

A. Hittmair, Die Partikel be-, Dissertation, Wien 1882
A. Bogner, Die Verbalvorsilbe bi-, Dissertation, Hamburg 1933
I. Kühnhold, H. Wellmann, Deutsche Wortbildung, Typen und Tendenzen in der Gegenwartssprache, Bd. 1, Das Verb, Düsseldorf 1973


I think a rule of thumb is that inseparable prefixes are just unreliable in terms of telling you the meaning of the word. Separable prefixes are more reliable, to point where the prefixed verb does not always get a dictionary entry. I like the comparison of "ver-" with English "for-". I think many English speakers wouldn't even consider "for-" a prefix, at least not in the same way as "de-" means to undo. In both languages you have to use care; "delight" does not mean "make dark" as you might expect from the prefix.

I have a website for that.
https://germanprefixes.com/prefix/ver/
Still a bit glitchy and in beta, but we're trying to make it a good resource.
EDIT: OP is asking for a list, not an explanation. Please stop downvoting. I am answering the question.

As is, this is a link-only answer to a commercial website of your own making. One could say, this is some sort of on-topic spam. While it's ok to link your own website, if it is on-topic, an answer should always be able to stand on its own and be valuable even without the links being followed. If you amend your answer accordingly, you might prevent downvotes being gathered (and you should know all this, given your reputation and gathered badges)

@planetmaker point taken! It's been years since I have been active here, so I forgot the rather strict rules (which are good).
HOWEVER, the question was about someone having a list of sorts, NOT for an explanation. To me, this is a question for a resource, which is what I am offering with my answer. So I don't think downvotes are justified. Happy to hear your thoughts on this.
